# How to draw 2 TextViews in Android XML?

Tags: android, xml, textview

I want to draw 2 TextViews side by side just like the attachment. One of them is single line and another is multi line. I tried LinearLayout & RelativeLayout but none of the combinations was not my solution. The alignRight & alignLeft divide screen into 2 part and width of second line in textview2 exactly like first line and second line doesn't start in the begin of the screen!

I would like to be draw 2 TextViews separately not 1 TextView, because every of them has an onClickListener separately.

Any help be appreciated, Thanks.

[Attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csDq8.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think the only thing you can do is to split the second txtview in two parts.